# 2 level customised ExpandableListView ClassCastException

Tags: android, expandablelistview, classcastexception, baseadapter

I have mastered successfully two level ExpandableListView with custom layout in Child and innerChild row. The problem is that the group header of the firstlevel display well. the row of the second level are display partially because of the height of the first level ExpandableListView.
the first level ExpandableListView host a layout and this layout host another ExpandableListView which in turn host a custom layout which has tableRow from which data should populated dynamically.

I reviwed the tutorial located at http://harrane.blogspot.com/2013/04/three-level-expandablelistview.html suggested to use a custom ExpandableListView that will be used in the Adapter of the first level ExpandableListView.

```
class CustomExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {
public CustomExpandableListView(Context context) {
super(context);     
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
/*
* Adjust height
*/
heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }  
}
```

but when i replace the line of the first level ExpandableListView i got A ClassCastException when trying to expand the first level ExpandableListView.

here is the code when not using the CustomExpandableListview class in the first level Epandable list view:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) 
v.findViewById(R.id.eLV_bols_details_goods_list_item);
    ExpandableListAdapterGoodsSub eLVGoodsSub = new ExpandableListAdapterGoodsSub(context, gs.getGoodsDetailSegment());
    elv.setAdapter(eLVGoodsSub);
.
.
.
```

here now is the code that i whish to use so that the first level ExpandabaleListView doen't hide partially the inner ExpandableListView

```
CustomExpandableListView elv = (CustomExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.eLV_bols_details_goods_list_item);

    ExpandableListAdapterGoodsSub eLVGoodsSub = new ExpandableListAdapterGoodsSub(context, gs.getGoodsDetailSegment());
    elv.setAdapter(eLVGoodsSub);
```

the probleme with ClassCastException is over

```
CustomExpandableListView elv = (CustomExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.eLV_bols_details_goods_list_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the code,

```
CustomExpandableListView elv = (CustomExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.eLV_bols_details_goods_list_item);
```

by,

```
CustomExpandableListView elv = new CustomExpandableListView(YourActivity Context);
```

Comment: it doesn't display the inner ExpandableListView. the innerExpandable listView use a customise layout with TableRow in it. this method is used to display default ExpandableListView which hasn't custom layout